# Getting last-modified property from MarkLogic Java API

Tags: java, marklogic

I'm trying to figure out how to access the `last-modified` property of a file stored in MarkLogic via the Java API, but I'm coming up empty.

I tried getting to it via metadata, but for a simple XML file, I'm not seeing any metadata at all.  I have a test file stored in MarkLogic.  When I run this code:

```
    DocumentMetadataHandle metadata = new DocumentMetadataHandle();

    XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
    docMgr.read("/path/test_file.xml", metadata, handle);

    System.out.println("Output: " + handle.get());

    System.out.println("Properties:\n");
    for (Map.Entry<QName,Object> prop : metadata.getProperties().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Prop: " + prop.getKey() + ": " + prop.getValue());
    }
```

... I'm seeing the object I expect, but NO properties.

Am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to tweak something in the database definition to make this information accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the database configuration to make sure "maintain last-modified" is enabled. That setting is on the `/database-admin.xqy` screen.

Next, verify that the properties are available using the query console on port 8002. This is an XQuery interface, but you only need a simple query: `xdmp:document-properties('some-uri')` where `some-uri` is your document URI.

If `xdmp:document-properties` works, then you can be more confident that the problem is in the Java layer.

Comment: Bingo; "maintain last-modified" was not enabled.  The checkmark shall be yours in a moment.  Thanks!

Comment: Maintain last-modified is off by default mostly for the overhead it imposes: extra writes for updates and requiring properties fragments at all. Make sure you’ve considered these implications before turning it on. Having said that, properties can be a convenient way to manage metadata.